# how do you create a AutoHotKey spin macro?

Tags: autohotkey

I need something that repeats the keyboard keys "up, left, down and right" and repeats endlessly until the insert key is pressed to pause it. I'm not sure how i should approach this. Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not on a windows computer at the moment, so this code is untested

This is for ahk_L not ahk_basic.

You will need to create a hotkey to start this loop.
You should also make sure this runs only on the window you are indending, as well as a way to quickly exit the script, as the script may run away from you, causing you to restart the computer.

```
; While the physical insert key is up, send the keystrokes
While(!GetKeystate("Insert","D")) {
   Send {Up}{Left}{Right}{Down}
}
```

If this is for a game, (and I suspect it might be) you might need to use a difrerent send mode. See the [Autohotkey FAQ](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#games) for info on that particualr topic.